# Auto unmount after Every boot

Tags: drivers, unmount

I deleted Windows and installed Ubuntu perfectly in my pc. (128gb SSD for os+ 1TB). But after some days I mistakenly deleted my 1TB partitions and I had to manually parition Using Gparted. But after manual partiton, every time I start my pc, my HDD partitions are unmounted automatically.I have to mount after every boot and this is annoying. My 128GB SSD is Ok where i installed UBUNTU but facing problem with this partitions

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Its fairly simple to setup automount partitions on startup follow these steps.

Assuming you are using Ubuntu >= 20.4

Type `gnome-disks` in your terminal

Then in gnome-disks utility window

1. Select your HDD
2. Select your partion
3. Click on settings cogwheel
4. Select Edit Mount Options
5. Disable "User Session Defaults"
6. Select mount at startup and show in user interface
7. Click on OK
8. Enter your password for authentication and authenticate

Repeat this process for all your partitions then reboot.

If you dont have gnome-disks please consider installing and using it, its very user friendly and helpful utility.

```
sudo apt install gnome-disks
```